# Android AsyncTask Threads being recycled with old data

Tags: android-asynctask

I trying to access a REMOTE android service via an Asynctask called from an Activity.

I'm having a problem which I think is being caused by threads being reused. I'm using a Lopper in the AsyncTask and when it gets a thread that it's already been allocated by an earlier call to the remote service I get an error about there being only one looper allowed per thread. I don't think this because I'm trying to access the UI on the wrong thread.

I can mimic the problem with some very simple code. I've created a button on an activity and just press it 6 times. Hopefully someone can advise me how to get around this. I've tried checking for the looper not being null, but that just leads me to another problem, so I'd like to try and resolve this.

Here's my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



public void buttonClick(View view)
{

    MyAsychTask myAsychTask = new MyAsychTask() ;

    myAsychTask.execute() ;

}}
```

The AsyncTask

```
public class MyAsychTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)   {
        Log.wtf("Thead details", Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getState().toString() + " : Looper def: " +  ((Looper.myLooper()==null) ? "none" : "looper") ) ;

        Looper.prepare();

        Handler myHandler  = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // in real app process incoming messages here then quit looper
                  Log.wtf("executing message", " ") ;
                 this.getLooper().quit() ;
              }
          };

        new simulateREMOTEservice(myHandler) ;

        Looper.loop() ; 

        Log.wtf("exited looper", " ") ;

        return null ;
 }}

class simulateREMOTEservice{
public simulateREMOTEservice(Handler myHandler)
{
    Log.wtf("simulating REMOTE service", " ") ;
    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0) ;

}}
```

The log file is

```
10-18 19:00:12.420: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #1 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: none
10-18 19:00:12.420: A/simulating REMOTE service(3081):  
10-18 19:00:12.420: A/executing message(3081):  
10-18 19:00:12.420: A/exited looper(3081):  
10-18 19:00:14.280: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #2 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: none
10-18 19:00:14.290: A/simulating REMOTE service(3081):  
10-18 19:00:14.290: A/executing message(3081):  
10-18 19:00:14.300: A/exited looper(3081):  
10-18 19:00:16.140: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #3 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: none
10-18 19:00:16.150: A/simulating REMOTE service(3081):  
10-18 19:00:16.150: A/executing message(3081):  
10-18 19:00:16.150: A/exited looper(3081):  
10-18 19:00:17.830: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #4 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: none
10-18 19:00:17.840: A/simulating REMOTE service(3081):  
10-18 19:00:17.840: A/executing message(3081):  
10-18 19:00:17.840: A/exited looper(3081):  
10-18 19:00:19.480: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #5 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: none
10-18 19:00:19.480: A/simulating REMOTE service(3081):  
10-18 19:00:19.490: A/executing message(3081):  
10-18 19:00:19.490: A/exited looper(3081):  
10-18 19:00:21.810: A/Thead details(3081): AsyncTask #1 : RUNNABLE : Looper def: looper
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:76)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.example.testlooper.MyAsychTask.doInBackground(MyAsychTask.java:15)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.example.testlooper.MyAsychTask.doInBackground(MyAsychTask.java:1)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-18 19:00:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Apparently I can't close this myself, but it looks like I'm experiencing the same issue as comment 16 in the following link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915

Basically they are saying that you shouldn't use a Handler in an AsynchTask, so it looks like I'll have to find a different mechanism to return data from my remote service.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment take a look at the url code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915 , though I suspect the real problem isn't with the AsyncTask threadpool, but the fact that once you've created a Looper you don't seem to be able to remove it or replace it with a new one.